# How do I create a dynamically sized background with a sticky bottom element?

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to create a dynamically sized background with a sticky bottom element that fills the entire viewport but stays put when scrolled. Invisionapp is having a similar effect on their homepage. They are having this "trusted by" bar that appears at the bottom when you launch their page but when you scroll, it just stays still.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're looking for css positioning. [MDN Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: http://mystrd.at/modern-clean-css-sticky-footer/

Comment: Could you please add a jsfiddle or plunker?

Comment: I don't have any code for it at the moment. I simply didn't know what to use for it.